# Neo4j Bloom Not Showing Property Label

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, bloom

How do I get my neo4j bloom visual to display the lake_year property as the label? In the desktop browser it shows the lake_year property as the label.

[image: desktop has property]

[image: Needs property lable]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. On the right pane I selected nodes then the yellow circle under the "style" label. A panel opens to the left. I chose the "defualt" tab, then the "text" tab. There you can choose what you want displayed.

Comment: It  worked to rescue !

Comment: Where is it in the documentation ?